# Am I using NSUserDefaults wrong?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I've created a "Settings" model for my iPhone app. It only contains two properties and a class method for loading and one instancemethod for saving.

I load it as follows

```
+ (UserSettings *)getCurrent {
    NSUserDefaults *userPrefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    UserSettings *settings = [UserSettings new];
    settings.username = [userPrefs stringForKey:kUserNameKey];
    settings.password = [userPrefs stringForKey:kPasswordKey];
    [userPrefs release];
    return settings;
}
```

The problem that the handling with the NSUserDefault casts an exception;

> -[NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x50b220

I have imported my header with the constants which are defined as follows;

```
#define kUserNameKey    @"Username"
#define kPasswordKey    @"Password"
```

(I am aware of keychain and am planning on changing to that later on, but want to solve the userdefaults)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try removing the `[userPrefs release]` since you never retained or alloced it

Comment: I was under the impression that the "standardUserDefaults" function had to alloc it. That seems to have been my problem though. Thanks

Comment: rule of thumb: if and only if you alloc, retain, or copy it then release or autorelease it

Comment: All you need to know about Objective-C memory management: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 0):

How are your UserSettings properties defined for username/password?  They should be set to "copy" for strings.